# Защита от SQL-инъекций с помощью WAF

Tags: защита

может ли кто подсказать сайт или может приложение ,в котором можно протестировать свой WAF.Или же как можно импортировать его в какой-нибудь CMS.Заранее говорю,я новичек,написано 3 файла htaccess config.php и файл самого фаервола,если это нужно будет скинуть для удобство,сделаю с удовольствием,если кому-то покажется это глупым,но я не смог найти информации в интернетах.Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Код надо нормально писать, а не файрволлы городить.

Comment: @Qwertiy я не сайт или приложение пишу,а учусь на безопасника,но преподаватель не хочет ничего объяснять,а это нужно знать.

Comment: Об этом можно было написать в вопросе